Set different material for points (Geonodes)
I have two systems of particles (points) imported from alembic.
The problem is that I can't install a different material for each of these systems.
Only one is installed for everything.



You need to modify the Selection input on the Set Material node. It won't be very easy (or performant) to set a different material for each point individually but you can set it based on certain attributes you account for. You could set an arbitrary bool value of True in one of the groups, store that in a Named attribute and then join, then use that attribute as the selection for only one Set Material node.

(Using Blender 4.2.0)
If a selection mask is connected to the Set Material node, a warning reading "Point clouds only support a single material; selection input cannot be a field" is displayed.

A workaround is to add a named attribute to each point, then to use this attribute in the shader node graph to switch between two "materials".

Resources:
(Blender 4.2.0+)
